# Java scripts not working in ascx edit page?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

Hi I am new to `dotnetnuke`. `Javascripts` are not working in `ascx` edit page? here i Have provided full path to `javascript` . But its not working correctly in `ascx` page.

```
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "Jcrop", (this.TemplateSourceDirectory + "/Scripts/jquery.Jcrop.js"));
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "jquery.Jcrop.min", (this.TemplateSourceDirectory + "/Scripts/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"));
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "jquery.min", (this.TemplateSourceDirectory + "/Scripts/jquery.min.js"));
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "jquery.color", (this.TemplateSourceDirectory + "/Scripts/jquery.color.js"));
```

Answer (score 0):

DotNetNuke own javascript libraries conflict with jquery, read here to see some solutions http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Blogs/EntryId/2268/DotNetNuke-Tips-and-Tricks-11-Using-jQuery-in-DotNetNuke.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You might like to read this blog article and use the supplied code.  It takes the guesswork out of including jQuery libraries into your DotNetNuke modules.

[Implementing jQuery, jQuery UI and Javascript libraries across DotNetNuke Versions](http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/EntryId/75/Include-jQuery-in-a-DotNetNuke-Module-with-version-independent-code)

Comment: Link's broken. Since it seems to be your blog, might want to fix that.